# How to omit specific attributes in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to use `tailwind-merge` in my Vue component to prevent conflicting tailwind classes. The problem with the following code is that when I use `useAttrs` and add a class from the parent, the extra classes are added twice.

The easiest solution is using `props`, but I wonder if there is a way to use `class` attribute directly on the component itself.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
defineOptions({
  name: "FormInputLabel",
  // inheritAttrs: false, => this breaks the whole attribute injection
});

const { label = "", tag = "label" } = defineProps<{
  label?: string;
  tag?: "label" | "span";
}>();

const attrs = useAttrs();
const classAttrs = toRef(() => attrs.class);
</script>

<template>
  <component
    :is="tag"
    :class="twMerge(clsx('font-medium text-base', classAttrs))"
  >
    <slot>
      {{ label }}
    </slot>
  </component>
</template>
```

Comment: If the comp is expected to accept class prop then define it as a prop, that's it. attrs are to pass an unspecified amount of props that are tedious or impossible to fully list

Comment: But you cannot define `class` as a prop name as far as I know. You need to name it something else.

Comment: You can, otherwise third-party comps wouldn't be able to normally use it. They certainly don't handle attrs in a roundabout way like you tried to do. It's reserved word and you can't call a variable `class` when you destructure props, so rename it where necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may transmit all of the attributes from the parent component to a child component in Vue 3 by using the v-bind="$attrs" functionality.

```
<template>
  <component
    :is="tag"
    :class="twMerge(clsx('font-medium text-base', classAttrs))"
    v-bind="{ ...$attrs, class: undefined }"
  >
    <slot>
      {{ label }}
    </slot>
  </component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `useAttrs`, and adding `:class="twMerge(clsx('text-base font-medium', $attrs.class))"` simple solved my issue.

Link: [https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes:~:text=%3C!%2D%2D%20MyComponent%20template%20using%20%24attrs%20%2D%2D%3E](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes:%7E:text=%3C!%2D%2D%20MyComponent%20template%20using%20%24attrs%20%2D%2D%3E)